# How to Restart Service Process on button click?

Tags: android, service, process

I have a service which is defined as a process in manifest all is working good but I want to restart that service on button click and the issue is, it is not starting again if it is already running.

```
 <service
        android:process=".UploadImage"
        android:name=".Service.UploadImageService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

when I don't define this service as process whenever I use intent to start a service. it always hits onStartCommand() of the service but when I defined it as a process startService(intent) not calling the onStartCommand().

Comment: When you call startService(intent) add an action to the intent --> `intent.addAction("ACTION_NAME")`, then inside the service, in `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` you can call `intent.getAction()` and handle the action as you want.

Comment: A comment on top of closing this as a dupe-  the design of an Android service is that it ISN'T restarted from onCreate.  Additional calls to start it cause a onStartCommand to be sent.  If you need something run every time, it should be there.  If you want any threads/resources in the old version ended, you need to code that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar as explained in the Android Documentation

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Use [Link for service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) from Android documentation. make sure you follow the Service state machine correctly as per your needs.

Comment: i have tried this but it stills give no reaction to my input

Comment: I know there are sometimes issues when you do not set the correct flag,  try to use this START_NOT_STICKY flag for your service

Comment: read little bit about flag here and choose as per your needs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY